# While trying to passing dotnet object one from another php file , Fatal error: Call to undefined method dotnet::

Tags: php, .net, object

I have a project on PHP and I have to use a DOTNET DLL which was written on C# . I have to call different functions of the same object in two different PHP pages. In the first page it works but I get this error in the second page. Can you please help me? These are example ;

DOTNET DLL :

```
namespace FirstDotNet
{
    [ComVisible(true)]    
    public class Class1 
    {
       public string SampleFunction()
       {
            return "hello";

       }
    }
 }
```

PHP Class File animals.php

```
class Animal{
 var $abc;

 public function do_it(){

   $this->abc = new DOTNET("FirstDotNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx", "FirstDotNet.Class1");

 }
}
```

First PHP FILE a.php (this works, output is 'Hello')

```
require_once("animals.php");
session_start();
$first_animal = new Animal();
$_SESSION["animal"] = $first_animal;
$first_animal->do_it();
echo $first_animal->abc->SampleFunction();
```

Second PHP FILE b.php (this doesnt work, output is Fatal error: Call to undefined method dotnet::SampleFunction())

```
require_once("animals.php");
session_start();
$animal2 = $_SESSION["animal"];
echo $animal2->abc->SampleFunction();
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure `DOTNET` contains a resource and therefore is not completely serializable. In other words, putting it in a session and fetching it won't end up with a complete object.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I see, so how can I do that? Do you have any opinion?